# How to add or upload file to nltk corpus?

Tags: python, nltk

I am to new to NLTK and Python. How do I add or upload our own file to nltk corpus? For example, how could I upload my own .TXT file to ieer corpus? Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably trying to do is read your own file using the nltk software. If you have a directory `/home/me/corpusdir` with files in ieer format, you should be able to open them with

myreader = nltk.corpus.reader.ieer.IEERCorpusReader(r'/home/me/corpusdir', '*.txt')

You can then call the same methods as on the real ieer corpus. Check out the documentation for `CorpusReader` and for the `ieer` module (which I've never used) for details.

If you really want to **add** your files to the existing corpus, you should either drop them into the `nltk_data` direcrory or (more complex but better in the long run) put a symlink from your corpus directory to the nltk ieer directory, so that your reader will treat the original ieer files as a subdirectory of your corpus.